# How to skip a line in my current program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got this code. This code removes the stopwords(in the stopwords.py file) from yelp.py

```
def remove_stop(text, stopwords):
    disallowed = set(stopwords)
    return [word for word in text if word not in disallowed]
text = open('yelp.py','r').read().split()
stopwords = open('stopwords.py','r').read().split()
print(remove_stop(text, stopwords))
```

Currently, the output is a very long string. 
I want the output to skip a line after every word in the yelp.py file. 
How do i do that? Can somebody help pls!!

The current output is ['near', 'best', "I've", 'ever', 'price', 'good', 'deal.', 'For', 'less', '6', 'dollars', 'person', 'get', 'pizza', 'salad', 'want.', 'If', 'looking', 'super', 'high', 'quality', 'pizza', "I'd", 'recommend', 'going', 'elsewhere', 'looking', 'decent', 'pizza', 'great', 'price,', 'go', 'here.']

How do i get it to skip a line?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have collected your output, a `list l`, you can print it as

```
print(*l, sep="\n")
```

where the `*` operator unpacks the list. Each element is used as a separate argument to the function.
Moreover, with the `sep` named argument you can customize the separator between items.

Full updated code:

```
def remove_stop(text, stopwords):
    disallowed = set(stopwords)
    return [word for word in text if word not in disallowed]

text = open('yelp.py','r').read().split()
stopwords = open('stopwords.py','r').read().split()
output = remove_stop(text, stopwords)
print(*output, sep="\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! It works.
I ran the code in powershell. However, I realised that yelp.py still has the stopwords. How do I remove the stopwords in stopword.py from yelp.py?

Answer (score 0):

When you print a list you get one long list as ouput `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`. Instead of printing the list you could iterate over it:

```
for e in my_list:
    print(e)
```

and you will get a newline after each element in the list.